# Profile Action PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts: Unable to resolve outbound message endpoint for relying party

Tags: shibboleth, idp

we are trying to migrate shibboleth idp verison from 3.1.1 to 3.4.4 and we are getting below error

[net.shibboleth.idp.saml.profile.impl.PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts:410] - Profile Action PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts: Unable to resolve outbound message endpoint for relying party 'https://ipau.sp.sso.manager/sso': EndpointCriterion [type={urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}AssertionConsumerService, Binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST, Location=https://172.29.241.168:8086/SSOSPManager/SSO, trusted=false]
2019-08-16 13:11:26,832 - 172.29.241.168 - WARN [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.LogEvent:105] - A non-proceed event occurred while processing the request: EndpointResolutionFailed

please find below assertionConsumerService Configurations in our SP metadata file

```
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="http://172.29.241.168:8085/SSOSPManager/SSO" index="1" isDefault="true"
  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="https://sp.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign" index="2"
  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="https://sp.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/Artifact" index="3"
  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="https://sp.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/ECP" index="4"
  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:PAOS"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="https://sp.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/POST" index="5"
  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="https://sp.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/Artifact" index="6"
  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have solved already but...
Seems that the url in metadata misses an "s" in
Location of default service and also port is different, so basically Endpoint misconfig, either in static (?) metadata or.. at the SP when sending messages (since the setting and check is based on the "inbound" message" and sp metadata).

It is.. strange that the same SP, accessed in same way, was working fine before..but maybe the check was added later.